# Modelling two kinds of objects with the same behavior

Tags: haskell

I have two types of objects with the same properties, namely: `Fuel` and `AdBlue`. Both are `Fluid`s and they share the same logic.

```
data Fluid a = Fluid { volume :: Double, price :: Double, kind :: a }
```

The fields `volume` and `price` must be non-negative. The `kind` field is to distinguish what type of fluid it is. I've tried the following code.

```
data FuelType
  = Diesel
  | SuperE10 -- 90% octane with 10% ethanol (Super is gasoline)
  | Super -- 95% octane
  | SuperPlus -- 98% octane
  | LPG

type Fuel = Fluid Fueltype
```

However, this make the API very clunky to use and it just doesn't feel right. How would you do it?

The types are used to determine whether a vehicle can be refueled with a certain type of fuel. For example, you can't fill a diesel engine up with gasoline and vice versa. Diesel engines with the new EURO6 emissions norm need AdBlue.

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: How about kind :: fueltype, no a?

Comment: It depends how they are used later in the program. If it is just about pricing things, why not `data Fluid = Diesel {...} | Gasoline {...} | LPG {...} | AdBlue {...}` where the ellipses is always `volume :: Double, price :: Double`.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Later on, they are used to check whether an engine is compatible with said fuel (can't throw gasoline in a diesel engine) and whether somebody filled up their AdBlue reservoir.

Comment: @typetetris I didn't specify that in the question, but gasoline also has quite a few octane ratings. For example, 95%, 98%, 95% mixed with 10% ethanol. Would these also be new types in your answer?

Comment: Maybe the `Has` type class pattern is good for you. The idea is to have a type class named `HasFluidProperties` which has two methods: `volume` and `price`. Then you instantiate `FuelType` or If you prefer, create different types for each case. https://hackernoon.com/the-has-type-class-pattern-ca12adab70ae

Comment: A type family might be a solution. See https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families. The relationship of an engine to the type of fuel it can use feels similar to the relationship between a map and the type of keys it uses.

Comment: @typetetris I tried your method. It sadly gets in the way of the fuel compatibility check.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. This design is the one I would choose given what you have described about your problem (I might de-parameterize the fuel type as @FrownyFrog suggested, until I found a good reason to make it polymorphic). What's clunky when you try to use it?